# Phonegap Build - How to add Custom iOS Framework (Embedded Binaries)

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, ios-frameworks, phonegap-cli, tealium

Our application uses the custom iOS frameworks as a plugin i.e. Tealium. Those plugin libraries are needs to be added in Xcode embedded binaries section.

As of now I can't see any provision in phonegap which can automatically add those binaries into embedded binaries. So if I use the local phonegap cli then I have to manually add those frameworks from linked libraries to embedded libraries. Now the issue is when I generate the build for ios.

PhoneGapBuild doesn't allow me to add the required plugins specific libraries directly into the Embedded Libraries which is causing in Library not found error and also which leads into crashing of the application.

All I want to know is how can I use PhoneGapBuild to put some plugins libraries into embedded binaries section of Xcode. Does the paid version will provide me that customization ?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm the maintainer of this plugin for Tealium. The latest version of the plugin uses Cocoapods for the binary dependencies, and does not require the manual embedded binaries step. This should play nicely with Phonegap Build and other remote build tools. Let me know how you get on. The updated plugin is available via npm, or directly from https://github.com/tealium/cordova-plugin

Comment: Thanks @CPR for your comment. We did upgrade to Tealium v1.1.0 but it has some other issues so we had to revert to v1.0.2.
Is there any way we can make it work for v1.0.2.

Comment: @appu99 could you please enlighten me on the issues you faced? It may be better for you to raise a support ticket with us or open an issue on the github page with details. I do not recommend reverting, since several issues have been fixed in the latest releases

Comment: @Appu99 I should add that the latest plugin is 1.1.1, not 1.1.0, and 1.1.1 is the version that introduced CocoaPods and Maven for dependencies.